# Unit testing functions - passing dependencies as args vs global access

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, functional-programming, mocking

Consider a scenario where a function `A` depends on three functions — `P`, `Q` and `R`. `P, Q, R` themselves have been unit tested as they do some really complex computations. Now I need to test the function `A` and I have two options —

## Access `P, Q, R` directly from A

```
function A (params) {
   ... P() 
   ... Q() 
   ... R() 
}
```

**PROs:**  No mocking required except for params.
**CONs:** Unnecessarily testing the logic of `P, Q & R`.

## Inject `P, Q, R` as arguments into A

```
function A (P, Q, R, params) {
   ... P()
   ... Q()
   ... R()
}
```

**PROs:** `A` is tested in a more controlled environment, as `P, Q, R` as passed as args.
**CONs:** A lot of effort goes in keeping the mocked functions update to date with their original functions.

I want to know which approach is better of the two and how can I control their respective cons in a better fashion.

NOTE: `A, P, Q, R` are all [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: Maybe this [similar q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861372/how-to-test-a-tree-of-pure-function-calls-in-isolation) helps you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your functions `P, Q, R` are urinary, you can compose them.

```
// A drop in implementation of compose
var compose = function () {
  var fns = arguments;

  return function (result) {
    for (var i = fns.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
      result = fns[i].call(this, result);
    }

    return result;
  };
};

var X = compose(R, Q, P);

function A (func, params) {
  // Function body...
}

// Curry function A so that our new function B, matches the signature 
// of the version of function A in your first example from the original           
//question.
var B = A.bind(undefined, X);

// Function B now has the same signature and behavior of function
// A in your first example.
var value = B(args...);
```

Calling function `B` in this code will be equivalent to calling function `A` in the original questions first example.